# Magento 2 404 page is redirecting to catalog search page

Tags: magento2.3, url-rewrite, search, catalogsearch, 404-page

Magento 2 404 page is redirecting to the catalog search page.

Example-

[www.abc.com/test123](http://www.abc.com/test123)

it will redirect to the 404 page

but it is redirecting to [www.abc.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=test123](http://www.abc.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=test123)

How to stop this so that it will not redirect to the catalog search page?

Comment: Are you using amasty elastic search module?